# Customizing DisplayFormat beyond DataFormatString

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, string-formatting, number-formatting

I have a MVC 4 project where I would like to use functionality similar to `DisplayFromat`, but setting a `DataFormatString` is not enough. I would like a function to be called to format the string. Is that possible?

I have tested inheriting `DisplayFormat` but that just lets me set the `DataFormatString`.

I have looked at customizing `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`, but I don't see how I would make it call a custom function for formatting.

My particular case is that I need to format the integer 201351 as "w51 2013". I couldn't come up with a format string that does that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to expose a read-only property on your Model:

```
public class Model{
    public int mydata{get; set;}
    public string formattedDate{
        get{
            string formattedval;
            // format here
            return formattedval;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: In our case, for various reasons, we would prefer to do the formatting using data annotations.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom ValidationAttribute. Here is some code I use to validation someone has selected a drop down value.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public sealed class PleaseSelectAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private readonly string _placeholderValue;

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            var stringValue = value.ToString();
            if (stringValue == _placeholderValue || stringValue == "-1")
            {
                ErrorMessage = string.Format("The {0} field is required.", _placeholderValue);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public PleaseSelectAttribute(string placeholderValue)
        {
            _placeholderValue = placeholderValue;
        }
    }
```

Then Use it:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Customer")]
[PleaseSelect("Customer")]
public int CustomerId { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question